# Qt. Размещение кнопок на форме. Растягивание элементов в компоновке QGrid Layout

Tags: c++, qt, формы, виджет

Читаю книгу М. Шлее "Qt 4.8 профессиональное программирование на С++" и дошел до примера калькулятора на странице 116. Там создается массив кнопок и добавляется на форму, но кнопки одинакового размера.

Я хочу растянуть некоторые кнопки, чтобы закрепить навыки работы с компоновщиком QGridLayout.

Должно получиться, что-то такое (простите за paint)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лучше обращаться к каждому элементу массива через индекс или создать десять отдельных кнопок? 
И как можно растянуть кнопки?

Привожу код из файла calculator.cpp.

```
Calculator::Calculator(QWidget* pwgt/*= 0*/) : QWidget(pwgt) {    
    m_plcd = new QLCDNumber(12);
    m_plcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
    m_plcd->setMinimumSize(150, 50); 

    QChar aButtons[4][4] = {{'7', '8', '9', '/'},                           
                            {'4', '5', '6', '*'},                             
                            {'1', '2', '3', '-'},          
                            {'0', '.', '=', '+'}                            
    }; 

    //Layout setup     

    QGridLayout* ptopLayout = new QGridLayout;
    ptopLayout->addWidget(m_plcd, 0, 0, 1, 4);
    ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("CE"), 1, 3); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton(aButtons[i][j]), i + 2, j);       
        }
    }     

    setLayout(ptopLayout); 
} 

QPushButton* Calculator::createButton(const QString& str) 
{     
    QPushButton* pcmd = new QPushButton(str);
    pcmd->setMinimumSize(40, 40);

    connect(pcmd, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slotButtonClicked()));
    return pcmd; 
}
```

Метод calculate и кнопка "СЕ" не нужны для решения этой задачи, поэтому метод calculate и реализацию кнопки не привожу.

Comment: Дизайнером ИМХО проще спроектировать формы, а потом только логику останется закодить. Чем вручную писать куда в какой лайоут какой элемент класть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [`QGridLayout::addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2) есть перегруженная версия вызова с двумя дополнительными параметрами, которые задают, сколько столбцов/строк виджет будет занимать в сетке — `rowSpan` и `colSpan`. Их и следует использовать для построения подобных «калькуляторных» интерфейсов. Собственно в примере из вопроса этот метод уже используется для размещения `m_plcd` длинной на все кнопки.

Само собой, т.к. у кнопок в данном случае нет никакого порядка, то от создания оных в цикле в таком случае придётся отказаться и задавать всё самостоятельно, как-то так:

```
ptopLayout->addWidget(m_plcd, 0, 0, 1, 6);
ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("CE"), 1, 5); 
ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("1"), 2    , 0, 3, 1);
ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("2"), 2    , 1, 1, 4);
ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("3"), 2    , 5, 3, 4);
ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("4"), 2 + 1, 1, 1, 1);
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Любой QWidget (QPushButton его наследник) имеет метод `QWidget::setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy horizontal, QSizePolicy::Policy vertical)`.

Чтобы, например, растянуть кнопку на все доступное пространство надо вызвать его так:

```
button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

Так как вы создаете все в ручную, то можно создать структуру инициализации создаваемой кнопки и передавать ее в метод createButton. Что-то типа такого:

```
struct BB
{
    BB(QChar char, QSizePolicy::Policy h = QSizePolicy::Prefered, QSizePolicy v = QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QChar label;
    QSizePolicy::Policy h;
    QSizePolicy::Policy v;
}
```

Далее поменять ваш 2D массив на такой (неторопливо и аккуратно):

```
BB aButtons[4][4] = {{BB('7'), BB('8')...,}
                     {...},
                     {BB('=', QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding), ...}
                    }};
```

Ну и изменить аргумент функции создания кнопки:

```
QPushButton* createButton(const BB& bb) {
    //...
    button->setText(bb.text);
    button->setSizePolicy(bb.h, bb.v);
}
```

Кроме того, в структуру BB вы можете добавить другие необходимые настройки.

Но как заметил @vegorov дизайнером это сделать намного проще.